# Connecting LSTM to a fully connected layer in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Im trying to make a connection from an LSTM layer to a fully connected layer in Tensorflow using the following code:

```
# lstm_outputs has shape 1x10x100
rnn_out = tf.reshape(lstm_outputs, [-1, 100])
# rnn_out has shape 10x100
```

Now I want to add a 1x10 vector to the output from the RNN and feed this new tensor into a fully connected layer.

```
extra_params = tf.placeholder(shape=[1,10], dtype=tf.float32)
fc_input = tf.concat(1,[rnn_out,extra_params])
fc1 = slim.fully_connected(fc_input,o_size,
    activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
    weights_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(),
    biases_initializer=None)
```

However the code gives me the following error on the `tf.concat` line:

> TypeError: Expected int32, got list containing Tensors of type
>   '_Message' instead.

I have two questions related to this code:

1. What do I need to do to get the expected tensor to feed into the fully connected layer?
2. What am I actually feeding into my fully connected layer? Is it a 1x1010 tensor or is it a 10x110 tensor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're using TensorFlow 1.0, the `TypeError` is caused by the incorrect order of arguments to [`tf.concat()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat) (which switched sometime around TensorFlow 0.12): it expects a list of `tf.Tensor` objects first, followed by the axis along which you want to concatenate those tensors.

However, if you simply reverse the arguments (`tf.concat([rnn_out, extra_params], 1)`) you will get a shape-related error. `tf.concat()` requires that all of its inputs have the same dimensions, *except* in the axis along which you are concatenating. However, `rnn_out` is a 10 x 100 matrix, and `extra_params` is a 1 x 10 matrix, so these tensors are not compatible for concatenation.

The correct solution depends on what the `extra_params` are supposed to represent. For example, if 10 is the batch size in your training, you might transpose `extra_params` into a 10 x 1 matrix. The following program should work:

```
rnn_out = tf.reshape(lstm_outputs, [-1, 100])
extra_params = tf.placeholder(shape=[10, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
fc_input = tf.concat([rnn_out, extra_params], 1)
```

Comment: My  batch size is 1, the input to the LSTM layer has shape 1x10x25. This is why im a bit confused when adding extra_params, I would like the input the the fullyconected layer to be a single row vector 1xNone but now it has one row for each timestep in the LSTM layer (10). Im lost on how to actually do this. Any comments on my second question n the query?

Comment: Hmm, in that case I guess you might be wanting to apply the fully connected layer to each LSTM timestep independently. In that case, you can keep the `tf.reshape()` as-is, and use `tf.tile()` to make `extra_params` the correct shape for the fully-connected layer: e.g. `fc_input = tf.concat([rnn, tf.tile(extra_params, [10, 1]))`